# [Python][Flask] PyLint too many instance attributes, is this resource correctly written?

Tags: python, flask-restful, pylint

I am writing an application in Python using Flask, now during creation of a Resource class for an endpoint I get a Pylint 'too-many-instance-attributes' warning. Now I do not know anymore if what I am doing is even a 'correct' way of writing Resources.

I inject dependencies into the resource like this:

```
api.add_resource(TicketsQuery, '/tickets/query',
             '/ticket/query/<int:ticketID>',
             resource_class_kwargs={'cleaner': Cleaner(StrategyResponseTickets()),
                                    'machine_cleaner': Cleaner(StrategyResponseMachines()),
                                    'db': soap_caller,
                                    'cache': cache,
                                    'field_map': app.config['FIELD_FILTER_MAP']['TICKETS'],
                                    'endpoint_permission': TicketsQueryPermission
                                    })
```

Which then shows up in the Resource as a kwargs argument. I also decorate the functions inside the init since I need a variable from the class (to do the decoration itself).

```
class TicketsQuery(Resource):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    # Dependencies
    self.cleaner = kwargs['cleaner']
    self.machine_cleaner = kwargs['machine_cleaner']
    self.db = kwargs['db']
    self.cache = kwargs['cache']
    self.field_map = kwargs['field_map']
    self.endpoint_permission = kwargs['endpoint_permission']

    # Permissions of endpoint method calls, implemented using wrapper
    self.get = authorization_required(self.endpoint_permission, UserType.GENERIC_EMPLOYEE)(self.get)
    self.post = authorization_required(self.endpoint_permission, UserType.GENERIC_EMPLOYEE)(self.post)

def get(self, permission_set: TicketsPermissionSet, ticketID=-1):
```

Is this a correct way of writing Resources in Flask? Or is there a better structure to adhere to? Any insight or tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't be discouraged by a linter warning ~ it's there to remind you to stick to a specific style. If you don't yet have a `.pylintrc` in the project's root folder then the linter will be using the default rules; this is simply a style warning against "too many variables in instance" ~ i.e. too many `self.*`'s - *it is 100% a pylint thing, and nothing to do with Flask*.

You can suppress the warning on this but keep it active for any others by adding a comment `# pylint: disable=too-many-instance-attributes` above the class's `def __init__(...):`.

If you'd like a more *pylintesque* way of solving it, run `pylint --generate-rcfile` (assuming you've `pip install pylint`'d and these messages aren't just coming from the IDE) in your project's root folder to generate a `.pylintrc`.

From there you can add the error's code `R0902` to the `disable=` list ~ i.e. `disable=R0902`, or `disable=A*,B*,R0902` ~ if you're disabling multiple warnings (which accept globbing, so you *could* just disable *ALL* `R*` messages, but it's best to only do that if you're sure you know what warnings you're turning off). **OR**, you can find the line `max-attributes=` under `[DESIGN]` and set/up that number to a higher value you'd consider more reasonable.

For reference, the resources to find this information if you'd like to explore further ~ [here's a list of the warnings you can get from pylint](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/features.html) which you can search either by the name of the error `too-many-instance-attributes` or by its code `R0902`, and [here's a sample pylintrc](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/main/pylintrc), which you can *mostly* browse by the code i.e. `R0902` to find the property in it that affects that warning.

Lastly, here's another SO article on the same pylint error message, if you want more examples ~ [How to deal with Pylint's "too-many-instance-attributes" message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434510).